# Open URL without leaving application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, inappbrowser

I'm developing an application for various platforms, including Android using Unity3D 5.

Currently to open a URL, I'm using the following `C#` code:

```
Application.openURL("http://example.com");
```

I would like to open links without leaving the application. I really like the Facebook app implementation, where the URL gets opened in a popup-style InApp web browser and can be closed easily without affecting the user's browser.

Comment: How about a `WebView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got to https://prime31.com/plugins and get the Android Etcetera plugin then they have a really easy implementation of opening a WebView within your app so that you don't have to leave the app.